# multiplatform change password

Tags: freebsd, pam, passwd

We are trying to standardize on  `passwd` to change our *nix passwords.  On linux, it's a simple matter of:

```
printf "secret\nsecret\n" | passwd username
```

But FreeBSD has re-written their version of `passwd` to use the `pam`
library.  The `pam` system uses [openpam_ttyconv](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=openpam_ttyconv&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD%2011.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html) to read the password,
which jumps through some hoops to defeat an administrator's attempts to
redirect stdin.

If you try the above recipe on FreeBSD, it will still prompt to the tty to and wait for an interactive response. If you try to fork and force stdin redirection, you get a `pam_chauthtok: conversation failure`

I understand on FreeBSD we can use

```
printf "secret\nsecret\n | pw usermod -n username -h0
```

But I was hoping (dreaming maybe) that someone might know a trick to
get the pam library to accept stdin redirection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard answer to problems involving interactive entry of passwords is to use [expect](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html) to run the command - passwd in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`chpass`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=chpass&sektion=1) to change a password from a script on *BSD, and the similar utility [`chpasswd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/chpasswd.8.html) on Linux. Both allow you to set the “encrypted” password for an account — actually the [password hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function#Key_stretching). You can call the [`crypt`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=crypt&sektion=3) function from a Perl or Python script to calculate the hash (don't forget to select a hash function, a random salt and a good iteration count).

Comment: This was an excellent suggestion -- but I went with icarus as the 'correct' answer.